# Will the baggage be allowed while travelling from India to USA?

Tags: usa, india, emirates

I am travelling from Mumbai to Boston with student offer that includes 3 baggage of 23 kg each. According to the emirates [website](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx), dimension of each baggage must be less than 150cm(L+W+H).

All my bags are having dimensions of 154-156 cm. So can anyone, who have flied recently with such situation, can tell me whether my bags will be allowed or not? Do they check dimensions of checked in baggage?

If I will be charged extra fees for exceeding dimensions, what will that fees be?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Emirates website](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/baggage-calculator-result.aspx?departure=bom&arrival=bos&class=y&tier=sn&h=85785b1dd26ab4c5f62e5aaf61e7c58e0f2d653), with my emphasis:

> Total dimensions (length + width + height) of each piece must not
>   exceed 150cm (59 inches). **Customers with individual items exceeding
>   above dimensions up to 300cm (118 inches) will be charged an
>   additional fee.** Individual items with total dimensions exceeding 300cm
>   (118 inches) cannot be transported as checked baggage, and must be
>   sent as cargo or freight.

So it seems you will be charged a fee, if your item *appears to be significantly larger than the allowed limit*. I have yet to see someone take a measuring tape out at the checkin desk in all my flights on Emirates, so how strictly this policy is enforced I do not know.

However, if you run into an especially astute check in agent, be ready to [a] beg for forgiveness [b] pay for the excess.

Answer (score 0):

Airlines flying out of India are normally far more lenient with students than with other travelers. As long as the baggage is not totally out of bounds e.g. 50kgs on a 23 kg limit, there should not be any trouble.

Comment: The first sentence is definitely an untrue generalization. Maybe some, but most don't care who you are.

Comment: @JanDoggen Maybe not generalized to ALL airlines out of ALL destinations. Have amended the answer to say airlines flying out of India. This is true based on personal experience.