# Marginally excess size baggage on Emirates?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, emirates

My luggage dimensions (L+W+H) are 157 cm, only one bag but the maximum size mentioned in the airline (Emirates) is 150 cm. Will this be a problem?what has happened in similar cases,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the baggage be allowed while travelling from India to USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96116/will-the-baggage-be-allowed-while-travelling-from-india-to-usa)

Answer (score 2):

You may get lucky, you may not - if you search around on this topic (as I did as I was worried about the size of my carry-on), Emirates goes both ways seemingly at random.  For some passengers they are very strict, for others they are lax almost to an extreme.

I checked in at Heathrow a few weeks back for a flight to Australia - my bags were simply put on the scales, rounded down to the nearest pound and then sent through.  My carry-on wasn't even glanced at (and that was the part I was worried about).

The family next to me were checking a veritable mountain of luggage, a lot of it outsized, without issue.

But as we walked away, I noticed someone several stalls down that were getting their luggage measured (and they had smaller bags than I did).

We were in Business class, they were not.  I guess that made the difference...